# Simple serialization example in c++

Tags: c++, serialization

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int test;
    std::string name;
} test_struct;
```

Then, I have the following code in the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    test_struct tstruct;
    tstruct.test = 1;
    tstruct.name = "asdfasdf";

    char *testout;
    int len;

    testout = new char[sizeof(test_struct)];

    memcpy(testout, &tstruct, sizeof(test_struct) );
    std::cout<< testout;
}
```

However, nothing gets printed. What's wrong?

Comment: Try NULL-terminating the string and adding a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeof(std::string) yeilds same value [always](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/164917-sizeof-std-string-seems-small). It will not give you the runtime length of the string. To serialize using memcpy, either change the struct to contain char arrray such as `char buffer[20]` or compute the size of the required serialized buffer by defining a method on the struct which gives the runtime length of the bytes. 
If you want to use members like std::string, you need to go through each member of the struct and serialize.

```cpp
memcpy(testout, (void *)&tstruct.test,  sizeof(int) );
memcpy(testout+sizeof(int), tstruct.name.c_str(),tstruct.name.length() );
```

memcpy against the entire struct will not work in such scenarios.

Comment: yes i know the output won't be useful but i still wanted to get at least something. i tried memcpy-ing the values separately (per above), but still it doesn't print anything...

Comment: @Mariska: What you are doing is lying to the compiler and it won't work. The `std::cout << testout;` line assumes that `testout` points to a null-terminated string of printable characters. It doesn't and you should research how actual serialization is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try NULL-terminating the string and also emitting a newline:

```
testout = new char[sizeof(test_struct) + 1];

memcpy(testout, &tstruct, sizeof(test_struct));
testout[sizeof(test_struct)] = '\0';
std::cout<< testout << std::endl;
```

However, as user3543576 points out, the serialization you get from this process won't be too useful, as it will contain a memory address of a character buffer, and not the actual string itself.